# Filter year from date type in semantic-mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I try to filter an #ask query in semantic-mediawiki to only display entries with a given year. I looked through the help pages but could only find how to display it, e.g. via the free formatting (F).

This is what I would like to try:

```
{{#ask:
 [[Has calendar::Work-calendar]]
 [[Has date#-F[Y]::2020]]
 |?Has date =Date
 |?Has appointment
}}
```

However, the `Has date#F`... part is not understood. What can I change to actually filter this table by a specified year?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use comparison

```
{{#ask:
 [[Has calendar::Work-calendar]]
 [[Has date::>=2020-01-01]]
 [[Has date::<2020-12-31]]
 |?Has date=Date
 |?Has appointment
}}
```

or pattern matching:

```
{{#ask:
 [[Has calendar::Work-calendar]]
 [[Has date::~2020-??-??]]
 |?Has date=Date
 |?Has appointment
}}
```